# Converting a degenerate representation of Gaussian to a non-degenerate representation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose that $x_i, y_i$ are i.i.d. standard normal random variables. Consider the following random vector

\begin{align}
z = \begin{bmatrix}
z_0\\
z_1\\
z_2\\
z_3\\
\vdots\\
z_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_1 + y_1\\
x_1 + x_2 + y_2\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + y_3\\
\vdots\\
x_1 + \dots + x_{n-1} + y_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

This random vector is jointly Gaussian because it is written as a linear combination of i.i.d. random variables. However, I think this representation of $z$ is degenerate. Can I represent $z$ as a linear combination of $n$ i.i.d. standard Gaussian variables? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see what happen with $n=2$. Define 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)^{\top}$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)^{\top}$, then 
$$
Z = AX+BY.
$$
Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, 
$$
\Sigma:=Cov(Z) = ACov(X)A^{\top} + BCov(Y)B^{\top} = AA^{\top} + BB^{\top}
$$
Its easy to see that $\Sigma$ is singular, so Z is "degenerate", i.e., lives in a lower dimensional space.